# How can I get the oauth client name on the login page with Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

When I follow the flow of authenticating my app via Laravel Passport, I'd like to inform the user which app (OAuth client) they're logging into. After logging in and being redirected to the authorization page, the client details are retrieved.

I've checked the `Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize`, but it doesn't look like it's setting anything other than a session variable `promptedForLogin`.

How can I get those client details on the login page?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a middleware class in the `web` group that checks if the request is for `/oauth/authorize` (the first step in the flow), and sets the client id found in the request:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    if ($request->is('oauth/authorize') && $request->isMethod('get') && $request->has('client_id')) {
        $request->session()->put('passport_client_id', $request->input('client_id'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now in my controller for showing the login page, I can retrieve the client name.

```php
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

$client = session('passport_client_id')
    ? Passport::client()->find(session('passport_client_id'))
    : null;

$clientName = $client?->name;
```

Finally, I forget the `passport_client_id` from the session by listening for the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` event in my EventServiceProvider.

```php
public function handle(Login $event): void
{
    session()->forget('passport_client_id');
}
```

This is quite an involved solution, but the only one I could find to improve my user experience in the OAuth flow.